# node js rest api for crud application

Tags: node.js, sql-server, rest, crud

I have started off with a REST API creation using Node.js. I have designed create and read functions and tested functionality using postman. Can you suggest how to add update and delete functions to it?

My dboperations.js file

```
var config = require('./dbconfig');
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
 

async function getFilms(){
    try{
        let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let films = await pool.request().query("SELECT * from Film8node");        
        return films.recordsets;
    }
    catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}

async function getFilm(Film_id){
    try{
        let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let films = await pool.request()
        .input('input_parameter',sql.Int,Film_id)
        .query("SELECT * from Film8node where Film_id = @input_parameter");        ;
        return films.recordsets;
    }
    catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}

async function addFilm(Film8node){
    try{
        let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let insertFilm = await pool.request()      
        .input('film_name',sql.VarChar,Film8node.film_name)
        .input('actor',sql.VarChar,Film8node.actor)
        .input('actress',sql.VarChar,Film8node.actress)
        .input('pub_date',sql.VarChar,Film8node.pub_date)
        .input('director',sql.VarChar,Film8node.director)
        .input('producer',sql.VarChar,Film8node.producer)
        .input('prod_cost',sql.VarChar,Film8node.prod_cost)
        .input('dist_cost',sql.VarChar,Film8node.dist_cost)
        .input('category',sql.VarChar,Film8node.category)
        .input('cert_category',sql.VarChar,Film8node.cert_category)
        .input('poster',sql.VarBinary,Film8node.poster)
        .query("INSERT into Film8node(film_name,actor,actress,pub_date,director,producer,prod_cost,dist_cost,category,cert_category,poster) values(@film_name,@actor,@actress,@pub_date,@director,@producer,@prod_cost,@dist_cost,@category,@cert_category,@poster)");  
        return insertFilm.recordsets;
    }
    catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}

async function updateFilm(Film8node,Film_id){
    try{
        let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let updFilm = await pool.request()    
        .input('Film_id',sql.Int,Film_id)  
        .input('film_name',sql.VarChar,Film8node.film_name)
        .input('actor',sql.VarChar,Film8node.actor)
        .input('actress',sql.VarChar,Film8node.actress)
        .input('pub_date',sql.VarChar,Film8node.pub_date)
        .input('director',sql.VarChar,Film8node.director)
        .input('producer',sql.VarChar,Film8node.producer)
        .input('prod_cost',sql.VarChar,Film8node.prod_cost)
        .input('dist_cost',sql.VarChar,Film8node.dist_cost)
        .input('category',sql.VarChar,Film8node.category)
        .input('cert_category',sql.VarChar,Film8node.cert_category)
        .input('poster',sql.VarBinary,Film8node.poster)      
        .query("UPDATE Film8node set film_name=@film_name,actor=@actor,actress=@actress,pub_date=@pub_date,director=@director,producer=@producer,prod_cost=@prod_cost,dist_cost=@dist_cost,category=@category,cert_category=@cert_category,poster=@poster where Film_id=@Film_id");
        return updFilm.recordsets;
    }
    catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}

module.exports = {
    getFilms : getFilms,
    getFilm : getFilm,
    addFilm : addFilm,
    updateFilm : updateFilm
}
```

My api.js file

```
var Db = require('./dboperations');
var Filmnode = require('./Film8node');
const dboperations = require('./dboperations');

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use('/api',router);

router.use((request,response,next) => {
    console.log('middleware');
    next();
})

router.route('/Films').get((request,response) => {
    dboperations.getFilms().then(result => {
        response.json(result[0]);
    })
})

router.route('/Films/:Film_id').get((request,response)=>{
    dboperations.getFilm(request.params.Film_id).then(result => {
        response.json(result[0]);
    })
})

router.route('/Films').post((request,response) => {

    let Film8node = {...request.body}

    dboperations.addFilm(Film8node).then(result => {
       response.status(201).json(result);
    })

})

router.route('/Films/:Film_id').put((request,response)=>{

    let Film8node = {...request.body}
    dboperations.updateFilm(Film8node,request.params.Film_id).then(result => {
       response.status(201).json(result);
    })
})

var port = process.env.PORT || 8090;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Film API is running at ' + port);

dboperations.getFilms().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
})
```

My Film8node.js file

```
class Filmnode{
    constructor(Film_id,film_name,actor,actress,pub_date,director,producer,prod_cost,dist_cost,category,cert_category,poster){
        this.Film_id=Film_id;
        this.film_name=film_name;
        this.actor=actor;
        this.actress=actress;
        this.pub_date=pub_date;
        this.director=director;
        this.producer=producer;
        this.prod_cost=prod_cost;
        this.dist_cost=dist_cost;
        this.category=category;
        this.cert_category=cert_category;
        this.poster=poster;
    }
}

module.exports = Filmnode;
```

Can anyone help me in adding a update and delete functions to this?
Is my ..[updateFilm].. method correct in "dboperations.js" file?

Also about the ...[ router.route('/Films/:Film_id').put((request,response)]... part in "api.js" file?

Comment: I'd recommend against using just `sql.VarChar` when specifying your input parameters. These should match the size of the columns in the database,  so if a column is defined as `varchar(50)` the input parameter should likewise be defined as `sql.VarChar(50)`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning noted.